# insert a line with file which has sed command in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to insert line in a file which will have a sed command to insert a line in another file
Like below for eg :
want to add this line `sed -i '1s/^/insideFile\n/' secondFile.sh` to **65**th line of `firstfile.txt`

I tried:

```bash
sed -i '65s/^/\'sed -i \'1s/^/insideFile\n/\' secondFile.sh\'\n/' firstfile.sh
```

but not able to escape the `'`

also tried

```
sed -i "65s/^/'sed -i "1s/^/topLine\n/" $FILE_HOME_LOCAL_FILE'\n/" secondFile.sh
```

but got
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed -i.bak "65s~^~sed -i '1s/^/insideFile\\\\n/' secondFile.sh\\n~" firstfile.sh
```

Note:

- Use of alternate delimiter `~` to avoid escaping `/`
- use of double quotes for your `sed` command to avoid escaping single quotes
- use of `\\\\` to insert a single `\`
- use of `\\n` inside double quotes to insert a line break

Alternatively with `i` (insert) instead of `s` (substitute):

```bash
sed -i.bak "65i\\
sed -i '1s/^/insideFile\\\\n/' secondFile.sh\\
" firstfile.sh
```

**Cleanest solution** would be to create a sed script like this thus avoiding all quoting and extra escaping:

```bash
cat ins.sed
65i\
sed -i '1s/^/insideFile\\n/' secondFile.sh
```

Then use it as:

```bash
sed -i.bak -f ins.sed firstfile.sh
```

Comment: Nice one, just a question is it a GNU `sed` specific the line number substitution OR this will work in most of the `sed`s? Thought to check with you on same, cheers.

Comment: This will work on any sed, I have tested with `gnu-sed` and `BSD` sed

Answer (score 2):

While `sed` allows you to do these things, it becomes a bit cumbersome when slashes and other control characters are involved. So it might be beneficial to use `awk` instead for this one:

```
$ awk '(FNR==65){print "sed -i \0421s/^/insideFile\\n/\042 secondFile.sh"}1' firstfile.txt > firstfile.new
$ mv firstfile.new > firstfile.txt
```

There are inplace possibilities, but if you come to think of it. Inplace is nothing more than making a temp to rename afterwards. This is exactly what `sed` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add this line `sed -i '1s/^/insideFile\n/' secondFile.sh` to 65th line of `firstfile.txt`

A scripted solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## uncomment to make sure firstfile.txt has at least 65 (e.g. 66) lines
# for index in {1..66}; do    
#  echo -e "$index" >> firstfile.txt
# done

# prepare the insert text, escaping the newline character twice
text="sed -i '1s/^/insideFile\\\\n/'"

# append to 65th line
sed -i '' "65i\\
$text
" firstfile.txt
```